# Apache 2+ basic authentication from db , not from files how to?

Tags: apache-2.2, database, http-basic-authentication

what plugins and what configuration do i need to configure Apache server to use user/password 
from DB and not from files to preform basic authentication

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the apache docs on [mod_auth](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_auth.html), specifically:

> A common use for this is in conjunction with one of the database
>   modules; such as mod_auth_dbm, mod_auth_msql, and mod_auth_anon. These
>   modules supply the bulk of the user credential checking; but a few
>   (administrator) related accesses fall through to a lower level with a
>   well protected AuthUserFile.

Comment: this is answering my answer what direction to go but far away from 
making it working working

Comment: That may be so, but becoming comfortable with the Apache docs is an important skill.

Comment: see my other question after reading and doing the config
http://serverfault.com/questions/307892/apache-and-mod-dbd-getting-dbd-mod-dbd-not-compatible-with-apr-in-get-driver