# Apache and mod_dbd Getting "DBD: mod_dbd not compatible with APR in get_driver"

Tags: apache-2.2, mysql, http-basic-authentication

Im tring to implement basic authentication with Apache server and plugin's 
the proxy part working great but when i try to preform request that suppose to trigger the 
mod_authn_dbd and its dependency's im getting this error:

```
[Sat Sep 03 17:42:38 2011] [error] (OS 126)The specified module could not be found.  : DBD: failed to initialise
[Sat Sep 03 17:42:38 2011] [error] [client 192.168.16.2] Failed to acquire database connection to look up user 'admin'
```

here is my configuration :

```
<VirtualHost 133.133.16.2:8090>
    ServerAdmin ed_mann@dont_spam_me.ok
    DBDriver mysql
    DBDParams "host=localhost port=3306 dbname=test user=root pass=root"

    DBDMin 1
    DBDKeep 8
    DBDMax 20
    DBDExptime 300

    <Proxy http://localhost:8080/jsp-examples/>
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from all
    AuthType basic
        AuthName "private area"
        AuthBasicProvider dbd
       # core authorization configuration
      Require valid-user

       # mod_authn_dbd SQL query to authenticate a user
       AuthDBDUserPWQuery \
       "SELECT password FROM users WHERE name = %s"
    </Proxy>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://localhost:8080/jsp-examples/$1 [P]

    DocumentRoot "D:/cpp/Projects/Game/workspace"
    ServerName localhost
    ErrorLog logs/dev30-error.log
    CustomLog logs/dev30-access.log common

    <Directory ""D:/cpp/Projects/Game/workspace">
    #
    # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
    # or any combination of:
    #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
    #
    # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
    # doesn't give it to you.
    #
    # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#options
    # for more information.
    #
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

    #
    # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
    AllowOverride None

    #
    # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
    #
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all

</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

what im doing wrong ?
mysql is working (phpMyadmin working great) and apache proxy working great .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use 64 bit windows and 64 bit mysql, try to change mysql with 32 bit version. Or you can put libmysql.dll from mysql 5.0 32bit in apache bin directory. Can get mysql 5.0 from mysql.org archives as zip file.